# Issue with many relationship fields in a channel

Tags: stash, relationships, related-entries, switchee, related

I have a channel with 4 relationship fields and each entry can be related to one or two relationship fields. and I hide unnecessary fields using ENTRY TYPE(http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-type) field type.
   In the template I am fetching the channel entries using fixed_order and based on entry-type  I am embedding a template with entry field values..all field values comes fine except relation fields and I am not able to understand why it directly show relationship field tags directly.
   My expression looks something like this

```
{exp:stash:set name="home_page_blocks"}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="pages"}
    {select_left_blocks}{select_left_blocks:entry_id}|{/select_left_blocks}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:channel:entries channel="blocks" dynamic="no" parse="inward" fixed_order="0|{exp:stash:get name='home_page_blocks'}" }
{exp:switchee variable = "{select_block_type}"}

{case value="news_article_block"}
    {title} || {related_news_article}{related_news_article:entry_id}{/related_news_article}
{/case}

{case value="case_article_block"}
    {title} || {related_case_article}{related_case_article:entry_id}{/related_news_article}
{/case}
{/exp:switchee}     
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Now this expression outputs

Entry title one || {related_news_article}{related_news_article:entry_id}{/related_news_article}

and I am not able to understand whats going wrong here,can anyone please help me out here

Cheers
Nisar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets tidy this up:

```
{exp:stash:set name="home_page_blocks" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}//Trim removes whitespace
    {exp:channel:entries channel="pages" backspace="1"} // Remove last '|'
     {select_left_blocks}{select_left_blocks:entry_id}|{/select_left_blocks}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

This should now output a list like "33|23|35" - test, test, test your output of this list as if it's broken here, the rest will fail.

Next you'll need to feed that to your other query:

```
{exp:stash:parse}//Wrap this in a parse block so its processed after the set above
  {exp:channel:entries channel="blocks" dynamic="no" fixed_order="0|{exp:stash:get name='home_page_blocks'}" }
  {exp:switchee variable = "{select_block_type}" parse="inward"} //Parse inward lives here

  {case value="news_article_block"}
    {title} || {related_news_article}{related_news_article:entry_id}{/related_news_article}
  {/case}

  {case value="case_article_block"}
    {title} || {related_case_article}{related_case_article:entry_id}{/related_news_article}
  {/case}
  {/exp:switchee}     
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Basically we've trapped your info in the required format (white space plays havoc with pipe delimited lists). Added a few stash additional stash calls and wrapped the "get" function in a parse to ensure it runs after the set (EE parse order takes some thinking/reading).

This is all untested and based on my own experience - it may or may not work as is, my code may not be perfect – but the approach is solid. You'll have to experiment your way through it. OR sit tight, be slack and wait for someone else to solve it for you ;-)

Have fun, try some different tags and see what  results you get - think of it as learning!

Comment: Also of note, the opening and closing relationships in the second case do not match: {related_case_article}{related_case_article:entry_id}{/related_news_article}

Comment: Thanks a bunch stuartmcd69..your suggestion worked out and sorry for not preparing the question in an untidy manner..